# How to make W3schools Modal example fade out?

Tags: html, css

From https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_modal_fade I have used the following CSS class to fade in. How can I fade out when the modal closes?

```
.w3-animate-opacity{animation: opac 0.8s}@keyframes opac{from{opacity:0} to{opacity:1}}
```

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<div class="w3-container">
  <h2>W3.CSS Animated Modal</h2>

  <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-button w3-black">Fade In Modal</button>

  <div id="id01" class="w3-modal w3-animate-opacity">
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4">
      <header class="w3-container w3-teal"> 
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" 
        class="w3-button w3-large w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
        <h2>Modal Header</h2>
      </header>
      <div class="w3-container">
        <p>Some text..</p>
        <p>Some text..</p>
      </div>
      <footer class="w3-container w3-teal">
        <p>Modal Footer</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should really make a snippet and show us the code your tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the selected answer at [How to get Fade-in-out modal effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45604025/how-to-get-fade-in-out-modal-effect)

It uses:

```
var id01 = document.getElementById('id01');

document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function() {
  id01.classList.add('w3-animate-show');
})

id01.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
  if (this.classList.contains('w3-animate-show')) {
    this.style.display = 'none';
    this.classList.remove('w3-animate-show')
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use jQuery,you can try these:

add an animation:

```
.w3-animate-show{
    animation: show 0.8s;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards; // means stop at the last status when animation finished
}
@keyframes show{
    0%{opacity:1}
    100%{opacity:0}
}
```

and in html code,change the span tag:

```
<span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').classList.add('w3-animate-show');" class="w3-button w3-large w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
```

but that just an animation ,the modal don't close at all, it just invisible.

Comment: Thanks. I did try that and it works -- but only once. After that clicking the button had no effect.

Comment: And here is another one trying to do it: https://jsfiddle.net/e280eLw1/